# How to dynamically insert items from a Array on one page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to direct the pages of `templateUrl` , en `route`, to the `wizard.html` page. To filter fixed items to their respective pages , I use:  `| filterBy: ['href']:'/sound-waves'` , for example. How could insert the items dynamically on one page ?

```
angular.module('tareasApp')
  .controller('NatureCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $sce, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    $scope.items =[
     {    
          href:'/sound-waves', 
          img:'waves.jpg', 
          video:'//www.youtube.com/watch?v=OG2eGVt6v2o',
          description:'Those Relaxing Sounds of Waves'
     },
     {    
          href:'/nature-relaxing-sound', 
          img:'ocean.jpg', 
          video:'//www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWR0GdC7_40',
          description:'Nature Sounds Relaxing Ocean Sounds'
     }
    ];  
 });
```

Page wizard.html

```
<div ng-controller="NatureCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="item in items | filterBy: ['href']: ''" >

    <img ng-src="images/{{ item.img }}" width="400" height="200" >

    <p>{{item.description}}</p>

    <iframe width="655" height="400" ng-src="{{ item.video }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>   
</div>
</div>
```

Route

```
angular.module('tareasApp')
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider

      .when('/sound-waves', {
        templateUrl: 'views/wizard.html',
        controller: 'NatureCtrl'
      })
      .when('/nature-relaxing-sound', {
        templateUrl: 'views/wizard.html',
        controller: 'NatureCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });    
  });
```

The goal is to avoid having multiple pages with the same structure.

**Edited:** The names of the pages are not in sequence so no . I had put to make it easier to understand . ( Had written as: page-one , page-two changed to sound-waves, nature-relaxing-sound )

**Edited:** Put the `...controller('NatureCtrl', function...` involving the items array for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that creating a route for each URL is the wrong way to go, which is why `$routeProvider` supports route params.

You can define your route as follows:

```
$routeProvider
  .when("/:pageName", {
     templateUrl: "views/wizard.html",
     controller: "NatureCtrl"
  });
```

and `pageName` will be available as a `$routeParam.pageName`:

```
.controller("NatureCtrl", function($scope, $routeParams){

   // ... pageName could be: "sound-waves" or "nature-relaxing-sound"
   $scope.pageName = $routeParams.pageName;
});
```

If the items are coming from a service, say `ItemsService`, you could also use the `resolve` property to obtain the items and even pre-filter them as they are coming from the service, as an inject-able parameter for your controller. Here's how it could look like:

```
$routeProvider
  .when("/:pageName", {
     templateUrl: "views/wizard.html",
     resolve: {
       item: function(ItemService, $route){
          // $routeParams here would not yet have the params for this route
          return ItemsService.getItemsForPage($route.current.params.pageName);
       }
     },
     controller: function($scope, item){
       $scope.itemForThePage = item;
     }
  })
```

Comment: The names of the pages are not in sequence so no . I had put to make it easier to understand, as would be the setting of the routes?

Comment: route params optimized is much more practical, except I had a title on each route and now do not know how to have page titles.

Comment: @ThiagoJem, well... one question at a time. If this solved your original issue, and you have a new one, ask a different question. This will give an opportunity to think about potential approaches

Comment: Part of the "resolve" I still do not understand. What parameters I need to put in "resolve" to the route ?  Items in my application comes from the array that is in the controller.

Comment: `resolve` was just an additional idea. `resolve` holds on view-switch until all the view dependencies are resolved, which could done asynchronously. So, specifically to your case, you could get the actual item for a particular view, or get all items, cache them, but `resolve` only the matching one. You don't have to use it. As in the first example, you could just get the parameter directly, which is what you wanted in your question.

Comment: I want to put the `items` of `array` dynamically in `wizard.html` page using a filter.
 The `wizard.html` has the same structure for all the `items` in the `arrays`, but I am using an html page for each, ex: `templateUrl: 'views/nature-relaxing-sound' ` -  `templateUrl: 'views/sound-waves' `

Comment: @ThiagoJem, I don't understand what you are saying. Your question was about how to parameterize the view url, which the answer achieves. Then you can do anything you want with this parameter. If the `resolve` part is confusing or misses your needs, ignore it.

Comment: I thank for the help in the optimization of routes .  I will do another question reformulated on the filter. Thanks brother!